# Cómo puedo hacer que mis eventos funcione con las teclas?

Tags: javascript, html

Hice una página web y me gustaria que al pulsar la tecla ENTER lea la palabra que se ha escrito, pero no se como lograrlo. ¿Alguno se le ocurre como hacerlo ?.

```
<body>
   <h1>Title</h1>
   <input type="text" id="guess-input" >
   <button id="guess-button">Try</button>
   <div id='grid'> </div>
   <p id="guesses">
</body>
```

Comment: Primero define "leer" en tu pregunta, porque yo leo, tu lees, Stan Lee, Bruce Lee, La Princesa Leía... Luego pon lo que has intentado y te guiaremos. Lee el [tour] y [ask] para una mejor guía.

Comment: Busca **eventos de teclado en Javascript**.  Cuando tienes el código y no te funciona según tu función, entonces ven aquí redacta tu pregunta junto con tu código y tu problema mostrando un ejemplo con tu código. Entonces habrá una solución. Por ahora tu pregunta está incompleto y es difícil que se te haga la tarea por ti. De echo, no se hace nada de tarea aquí...

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tienes la solución a tu problema espero te ayude.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <input type="text" id="guess-input" >
        <button id="guess-button">Try</button>
        <div id='grid'> </div>
        <p id="guesses">

        <script>
            const guessInput = document.getElementById('guess-input')
            const guessButton = document.getElementById('guess-button')
            
            guessInput.addEventListener('keydown',e=>{
                if(e.keyCode == 13){
                    read(guessInput.value)
                }
            })
            guessButton.addEventListener('click',e=>{
                read(guessInput.value)
            })
            function read(texts){
                console.log(texts)
                if(texts.length){
                    const synth = window.speechSynthesis
                    const utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(texts)
                    synth.speak(utterThis)
                }
            }
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Alguna breve explicación no estaría mal!